# Angular HttpClient cannot receive Multipart file

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I'm currenctly struggling with weird problem. I think that HttpClient still treats server's response like JSON...

Bellow my first method in @Component, still I've got 'error' in console.

```
downloadDocument(url: string) {
this.client.download(url).subscribe(response => {
  console.log('success');
}, error => {
  console.log('error');
});
```

}

And methods from object 'client':

```
download(url: string): Observable<any> {
return this.httpClient.get(url, this.prepareDownloadHeaders());
}

private prepareDownloadHeaders() {
const token = this.authService.getToken();
return {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
  })
};
}
```

And Chrome show that I received correctly file:
[image]

I tried many ways to resolve this issue like bellow and much more.

```
private prepareDownloadHeaders() {
const token = this.authService.getToken();
return {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Accept': 'application/pdf',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
    responseType: 'blob' as 'json'
  })
};
```

}

Comment: I think you need to observe the response, `this.httpClient.get(url, { responseType: 'blob', observe: 'response'});`

Comment: you can use file-saver npm package to save the blob

Comment: @JasonWhite but if I use options like you wrote I could not attach my bearer token ;/

Comment: You can add a headers property in that object.`this.httpClient.get(url, { headers: { 'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token },  responseType: 'blob', observe: 'response'});`.  You can also set `'headers' : this.prepareDownloadHeaders()'.

Comment: The second value of `HttpClient.get()` is an objects object, not only headers.

Comment: for images you convert the blob to a data URI and link it to the source of an image.  I don't know whether it its similar for other file formats.  there is a library called blob_utils which converts to all possible formats.

Comment: @JasonWhite thank You so much.This option `observe: 'response'` makes that everything works well for now. Have a nice day.